# Given an expression of the form `fn(NULL)` how do I replace the null with `lhs=rhs`?

Tags: r, nse

Consider

```
ex1 = quote(fn(NULL))
```

and suppose I wish to make `ex1` equals to `fn(lhs=rhs)` in expression form, how do I do that?

since

```
ex1[[2]] = quote(lhs=rhs)
```

gives `ex1 = fn((lhs=rhs))` and I can't seem to get rid of the parenthesis.

Comment: `quote(lhs = rhs)` gives an error since `quote` does not have an argument named lhs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```r
ex1 <- quote(fn(NULL))
ex1
#> fn(NULL)

ex1[[2]] <- quote(rhs)
names(ex1)[2] <- "lhs"
ex1
#> fn(lhs = rhs)
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

**1) as.call** Create a list formed from the function name and the arguments in name = value form and then use `as.call` to convert that to a call object.

```
as.call(list(ex1[[1]], lhs = quote(rhs)))
## fn(lhs = rhs)
```

In a comment @Allan Cameron suggested this variation:

```
as.call(c(ex1[[1]], alist(lhs = rhs)))
```

**2) call** Another way is to use `call`.  It requires a character string for the function name so use `deparse` to get that.

```
call(deparse(ex1[[1]]), lhs = quote(rhs))
## fn(lhs = rhs)
```

**3) character** Another approach is to create a character string representing the call and then convert that back to a call object.  Here `parse` creates an expression such that its first component is a call object.

```
parse(text = sprintf("%s(%s)", deparse(ex1[[1]]), "lhs = rhs"))[[1]]
## fn(lhs = rhs)
```

### Note

Input is:

```
ex1 <- quote(fn(NULL))
```